# What is a good way to define user roles in a mongo database

Tags: java, mongodb, user-roles

Coming from a relational db background I find it easy to break apart user and their roles into normalized tables. But what is the customary way to do this in a mongo database?

Scenario I have

```
({    "roles" :
    [
        {"role": "user"},
        {"role": "manager"},
        {"role": "admin"}
    ]

    "privileges" :
    [
        {"privilege": "READ"},
        {"privilege": "READ/WRITE"},
        {"privilege": "ALL"}
    ] 

    "users" :
    [
        {"user": "Sammy"},
        {"user": "Tom"},
        {"user": "Fred"},
        {"user": "Zack"}
    ]

    "userPermissions" :
    [
        {"admin": "Sammy"},
        {"manager": "Tom"},
        {"user": "Fred"},
        {"user": "Zack"}
    ]
})
```

**Question : Is this an appropriate way to model user roles in Mongo?**

Comment: Is this even valid JSON?

Comment: It wasn't before and it still isn't. Now I don't see the roles of the users.

Comment: That's better. Now add a root object around everything (`{ }`) and you have valid JSON :)

Comment: @LutzHorn awesome thanks. JSON wasn't my concern even though i butchered it :) But is this an appropriate approach with mongo? Is this typically how a mongo developer would break user roles down the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your roles are plain Strings or a primitive tuple, you can store them as `array` inside each User's document. If the role is a complex entity, you can store them as an array of doc-refs.

UPDATE:

this is a document from my `userAccount` collection, generated by `Spring Security Core Grails plugin`:

```
{
  "_id" : "541fdfdebaacef69047415a8",
  "authorities" : [ 
     {
        "authority" : "ROLE_USER"
     },
     {
        "authority" : "ROLE_ADMIN"
     }
  ],
  "password" : "lakdjalksdj87a68sd76as87d6a87sd6",
  "username" : "someusername",
  "version" : NumberLong(1)
}
```

`Spring Security` and it's descendants are the standard security implementations in java, so...

Comment: so where does this "authorities" tie back to. and how would i figure out what the other options were?

Comment: the `authorities` is mapped to the equally named property of the `UserAccount` domain class, which represents an array of `Authority` classes

Answer (score -3):

Mongo DB user roles are defined as JSON documents. Try the following links

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

https://scalegrid.io/blog/creating-role-based-access-control-in-mongodb/